# How can I write an Angular ngFor pipe to filter array of objects by object property?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-pipe

I have 2 selects.

One for `Leagues` and one for `Divisions`

I want to create a `Pipe` that will filter `Divisions` depending on what `League` is selected.

Giving the data below. If I select `Random Beer League` only `TwoFour` and `SixPack` should show up as options for the `Divisions` select.

```
leagues = [
  {id: 1, leagueName: 'Recreation League' },
  {id: 2, leagueName: 'Random Beer League' } 
];

divisions = [
  {id: 1, divisionName: 'SoGreen', leagueId: 1, leagueName: 'Recreation League' },
  {id: 2, divisionName: 'Yellow', leagueId: 1, leagueName: 'Recreation League' },
  {id: 3, divisionName: 'TwoFour', leagueId: 2, leagueName: 'Random Beer League' },
  {id: 4, divisionName: 'SixPack', leagueId: 2, leagueName: 'Random Beer League' }
];
```

[PLUNKER to show the setup](https://plnkr.co/edit/yoKPq3irZXiJ5xxS0sfO?p=preview)

*Note - data in plunker is hard coded but in my app setup its Observable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have create a custom pipe and used it to filter division dropdown.

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'myfilter',
    pure: false
})

export class MyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any {
        return items.filter(item => item.leagueName.indexOf(args.leagueName) > -1);
    }
}


<option *ngFor="let division of divisions | myfilter:leagueSelected" [ngValue]="division">{{division.divisionName}}</option>
```

Please look into this [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/xhUp7lbggJaVanoN7EFC)

Comment: I have updated plnkr link. The reason is angular2 renamed "ngOnChange" event to "onChange".