# comma separated string using ngFor with a condition?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to generate comma separated string from an array.

This is my data:

```
responseData= [{ name: 'Some Data 1', type:'action' }, 
               { name: 'Some Data 2', type:'action' },
               { name: 'Data 3', type:'NA' }, 
               { name: 'Data 4', type:'action' },
               { name: 'Data 5', type:'NA' }];
```

This is how I'm looping. **I only want to loop through `action` type**.

```
<div *ngFor="let data of responseData; let last=last">
    <div *ngIf="data.type=='action'">
        {{ data.name}} {{last?'':', '}}
    </div>
</div>
```

But I'm left with another comma at last. How do I remove that?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason last is not getting applied is because the last element is not of the type "action".

As a Fix, You can create a custom function to filter the initial data first and apply the same logic,

```
<div *ngFor="let data of filterFunction(responsedata); last as isLast">
    <div >
        {{ data.name}}  {{isLast?'':', '}}
    </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9smiim?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can this be achieved on html without a function or variable in `typescript`

Comment: no you cannot. you can use pipe instead which again has to be done with TS

Answer (score 1):

Since the filtering for type = action happens inside the ngForOf, the last element still not counted, so last is always false for your case.

I have added a new Array which is filtered based on type = action at the typescript and that works for me. See the example below at stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dfhpan

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) for this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'listify'})
export class ListifyPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(responseData: Array<any>, responseType: string): string {
        return responseData
            .filter(r => r.type === responseType)
            .map(r => r.name)
            .join();
    }
}
```

and then call it

```html
<div>{{responseData | listify : 'action'}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the 'last' binding (which is like checking if current iteration index + 1 is equal to array length) with a visually filtered array - it will not work since the actual array index will not be affected by your filtering.

You can either filter the array before using it in your template:

```
responseData= [
 { name: 'Some Data 1', type:'action' }, 
 { name: 'Some Data 2', type:'action' },
 { name: 'Data 3', type:'NA' }, 
 { name: 'Data 4', type:'action' },
 { name: 'Data 5', type:'NA' }
]
.filter(item => item.type === 'action');
```

Then, use it in your template without filtering

```
<div *ngFor="let data of responseData; let last=last">
    {{ data.name}} {{last?'':', '}}
</div>
```

...or, better, create a [custom pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) which will filter the array and keep proper tracking of the 'last' binding

There are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47017194/how-to-filter-based-on-property-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-angular2) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41603250/how-can-i-write-an-angular-ngfor-pipe-to-filter-array-of-objects-by-object-prope/41605715) so I will not provide another copy here, you will just need to use it as

```
...*ngFor="let item of myArray | myFilter;let last...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a conditional comma before each item value like:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index">  
   <span *ngIf="i > 0">, </span><span> {{ item.value }} </span>
</ng-container>
```

or

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index">  
  {{ i > 0 ? ', ': '' }} {{ item.value }}
</ng-container>
```